# Скрежет зубовный и мука мученская . Необычные формы прилагательных

Tags: этимология

Подбирала синонимы и нашла эти необычные формы прилагательных. Интересно, давно ли они появились и откуда. В каком контексте лучше употреблять?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. 

"Скрежет зубовный" из некоторых переводов Библии (Новый Завет, Евангелие от Матфея, 8:12):

```
SYN
а сыны царства извержены будут во тьму внешнюю: там будет плач и скрежет зубов.  
NRT
Сыны же Царства будут выброшены вон, во тьму, где будет плач и скрежет зубов.  
BTI
А те, кто должен был наследовать Царство, низвергнуты будут во тьму, где будет плач и скрежет зубовный.  
ERV
А те, кому следовало войти в Царство, будут ввергнуты во тьму бесконечную, и будет там плач и скрежет зубов от нестерпимой боли».  
RBO
А те, кому было предназначено Царство, будут изгнаны вон, во тьму, где будет плач и зубовный скрежет.
```

[Источник](https://bible-teka.com/vs/40/8/12/)

Церковно-славянский текст:

[image]

[Источник](http://www.my-bible.info/biblio/bib_tsek/ev_matf.html#g8)

Употребляется иносказательно: о гневе, досаде, раздражении; о слепой и бессильной ярости (ирон.).

2. 

Что касается выражения *мука мученская* (иногда через дефис), словарь Ушакова упоминает его с пометкой (прост.):

> МУЧЕНСКИЙ, мученская, мученское. Только в выражении: мука мученская (прост.) -  > очень сильная мука, тяжелые хлопоты. «Эти люди совсем занапрасно терпят **муку
>   мученскую** от своего начальства.»
>   Салтыков-Щедрин.

[Источник](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/dictionary-ushakov/fc/slovar-204-16.htm)

Также встречается у Достоевского, Аверченко, Бажова, Булгакова и других. ([Цитаты](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F)).

*Мука мученская* - один из примеров [Плеоназма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC), как и *тьма-тьмущая*, *день-деньской* и т.п.